# is there a way to somehow block certain pages (aspx) based on a condition MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, url, webforms

I have a customized authentication on the system, what I would like is for certain pages (ex. EditingProfile.aspx) to not be accessible through URL navigation. 
if a user is authorized: buttons (ex. btnEditingProfile) is enabled and would redirect to EditingProfile.aspx. 
is a user isn't authorized: buttons (btnEditingProfile) would be disable. I'm looking for a way to prevent users from accessing EditingProfile.aspx through URL navigation.

The system I'm working on is old so I need a safe way to secure it that wouldn't interfere with other aspects of the system.

MainMenu.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //CODE
        if (!m_mainController.m_IsAutorized)
        btnEditProfile.Enabled = false;
        //MORE CODE
    }
```

```
 protected void btnEditProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            queryStrings=SOMEVALUE();
            string QueryString = QueryStringEncrypter.GetEncryptedQueryString(queryStrings);
            Response.Redirect("ProfileDetails.aspx?" + QueryString, false);
        }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?  Looks like CLI or C#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please pay attention when you select tags, so you don't select the wrong ones. Please edit your question (there's a link below the tags) to correct it.

Comment: it seam asp.net webform not asp.net mvc

Comment: @nathanOliver you’re right it’s c#. I fixed it, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @hienNguyen I haven’t worked with asp.net webforms before so I couldn’t identify it. I’m new to all of this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Tim Nguyen's suggestion I did the following:

in MainMenue.aspx I added

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code        
    if (!m_mainController.m_IsAutorized)
    btnEditProfile.Enabled = false;
    Session["url"] = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
   //more code
}
```

in EditingProfile.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["url"] != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Session["url"].ToString());
            }
            //code
         }
```

nothing else was changed. The code is running the way I want it to so I thought id update this question in case someone need it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, each user should has an login session to know their permission.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21474/Easy-way-to-create-secure-ASP-NET-login-using-Sess

Comment: I didn't even consider Session variables! thank you.